# Openlayers 3 interaction.draw()

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to create a user interactive circle using the example code from the openlayers example website:

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
    type: 'Circle'
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

I always get a `TypeError` when I set, type: `Circle`, but when I set the type to `Point`, `LineString`, or `Polygon` it works just fine. I looked through the openlayers 3 API documentation and `Circle` is a valid geometric type. Does anyone here have any information of why I get the type error?

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circle was added to one of the latest version of ol3 (3.4) 
Now the latest version is 3.5
I made an example of adding Circle:

js

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.js
```

css

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.min.css
```

[Draw circle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2cP4/99/)

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform(
        [-110, 45], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 3
  })
});
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});

featureOverlay.setMap(map);


var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
    type: 'Circle'
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Comment: Thanks it was my version of Openlayers. I had ol v3.0.